# Напечатать слово с помощью указателей на начало и конец

Tags: c++

Дана строка, содержащая слова разделёнными пробелами и даны 2 указателя на начало слова и 2-ой указатель указывает на конец слова. Как вывести, например, 1-ое слово через указатель? Начал проходить тему указатели и не могу вникнуть

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
for(char* с = begin; c != end; ++c)
    std::cout << *c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если указатель `beg` указывает на начало слова, а `end` - на символ, следующий за концом:

```
printf("%.*s\n", end-beg, beg);
```

Если `end` указывает на последний символ слова, то к длине надо добавить единицу.

http://ideone.com/I7F3ht

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char *str = "Just some text inside of string";

    {
    char *beg = str + 5, *end = str + 9;

    puts(str);
    puts(beg);
    puts(end);

    printf("%.*s\n", end-beg, beg);
    }

    {
    char *beg = str + 5, *end = str + 8;

    puts(str);
    puts(beg);
    puts(end);

    printf("%.*s\n", end-beg+1, beg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Just some text inside of string
some text inside of string
 text inside of string
some
Just some text inside of string
some text inside of string
e text inside of string
some
```

Comment: давайте уже сразу *end =0; cout << beg; , чего мелочится)

Comment: @pavel, не понял. Update: Понял. Но константную строку даже при желании испортить не получится: http://ideone.com/ARMwKB

Comment: кстати на счёт при желании, это регламентируется стандартом что совсем никак не получится, или компилятором (опции версия и так далее)  ?

Comment: @pavel, формально это UB, если не ошибаюсь. Реально, константные строки размещены в readonly-памяти, поэтому приложение просто падает.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ с картинкой

```
abcdefg hijklmn
^  ^  ^
|  |  |
|  |  `-------- end
|  `----------- begin + 3
`-------------- begin

for(char* с = begin; c <= end; c++) cout << *c;
```

До пробела

```
abcdefg hijklmn
^  ^   ^
|  |   |
|  |   `------- end
|  `----------- begin + 3
`-------------- begin

for(char* с = begin; c < end; c++) cout << *c;
```

Или

```
abcdefg hijklmn
^  ^   ^
|  |   |
|  |   `------- space
|  `----------- begin + 3
`-------------- begin

for(char* с = begin; *c != ' '; c++) cout << *c;
```

Comment: я так же делал через while, только я пробегал по строке до 1-ого пробела и у меня бред вывод, может что-то напутал, буду разбиратся